# Unresolvable circular reference in Quartz job configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I'm trying to migrate old Spring project with Quartz to the latest Spring Boot:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class QuartzConfiguration implements InitializingBean {

  public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QuartzConfiguration.class);
  public static final String JOB_KEY = "FinalizationJob";
  public static final String KEY = JOB_KEY + "_Trigger";

  private ApplicationContext context;

  @Autowired
  public QuartzConfiguration(ApplicationContext context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Bean(name = "finalJobDetail")
  public JobDetail batchExpireUpdateJobDetail() {
    return JobBuilder.newJob(BatchExpireUpdateJob.class)
        .withIdentity(JobKey.jobKey(JOB_KEY))
        .storeDurably()
        .build();
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    Trigger newTrigger = newTrigger()
        .forJob(JOB_KEY)
        .withIdentity(triggerKey(KEY))
        .withSchedule(repeatSecondlyForever(100))
        .build();

    try {
      Scheduler obj = getSchedulerInstanceFromApplicationContext();
      if (obj.checkExists(triggerKey(KEY))) {
        obj.rescheduleJob(triggerKey(KEY), newTrigger);
      } else {
        obj.scheduleJob(newTrigger);
      }
    } catch (SchedulerException | NullPointerException e) {
      LOGGER.error("error {}", JOB_KEY, e);
    }
  }

  private Scheduler getSchedulerInstanceFromApplicationContext() {
    Scheduler obj = null;
    String [] beans = context.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    for (String bean: beans) {
      if (context.getBean(bean) instanceof Scheduler) {
        obj = (Scheduler) context.getBean(bean);
        break;
      }
    }
    return obj;
  }

  @DisallowConcurrentExecution
  private static class BatchExpireUpdateJob implements Job {

    private DatabaseService databaseService;

    @Autowired
    public BatchExpireUpdateJob(DatabaseService databaseService) {
      this.databaseService = databaseService;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
      try {
        LOGGER.info("Updating status");
        databaseService.updateStatus();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error ", e);
        throw new JobExecutionException(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the code I get:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzConfiguration': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

┌──->──┐
|  QuartzConfiguration defined in file C:\......\QuartzConfiguration.class]
└──<-──┘
```

Comment: 1. In `QuartzConfiguration`, I see `BatchJobQuartzConfiguration` is this correct?  
2. What is the `from` and `to` springboot version?(latest will change when time pass...)

Comment: Fixed. It's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you upgraded to `Spring Boot 2.6` so **"Circular references are prohibited by default"** that is the reason you get `BeanCurrentlyInCreationException` you can take a look here [circular prohibited by default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#circular-references-prohibited-by-default) so the issue here is because first when having annotated `@Configuration` for `QuartzConfiguration` a bean is created for. So when you call to get all bean names `context.getBeanDefinitionNames()` here you should find the `QuartConfiguration` bean name which is being a referenced by `context.getBean(bean)` this makes a **circular reference** for the same `QuartConfiguration` bean then the `BeanCurrentlyInCreationException` is thrown, so you have two options to solve this:

**First option**

You might call the `Scheduler bean` directly. You don't have the need to loop.

```
private Scheduler getSchedulerInstanceFromApplicationContext() {
    return context.getBean(Scheduler.class);
}
```

**Second option**

Allow circular references by setting a property in `application.properties` or `application.yml` which the property is:

> spring.main.allow-circular-references=true

Comment: Is this the best option for fix? Is there other solution?

Comment: I tried the first code but I get `Error creating bean with name 'quartzScheduler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/quartz/QuartzAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is  Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'quartzScheduler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzConfiguration': Requested bean is currently in creation`

Comment: The second  option is not working.

Comment: Hey! I assumed that you created a vean for Scheduler in another place, looks like you have another circular reference, please add that piece of code in the clases which is being called, so I can help you and edit my answer, the second one should be working. I am not pretty sure what output are displayed, add a stacktrace please for the second option, I tried and works, let me know it.

Comment: I already tried but it's not working for some reason.

Comment: Okay @PeterPenzov could you please add the code where Scheduler bean is being created and called? For example in you code here is called Scheduler. Another place?

Comment: Can you share your e-mail please?

Comment: Sure, you can see it on my profile,  send me a google meet, I can help you.

Comment: I will send you soon code example so that you can run it locally. Give me 20 min.

Comment: Please check your e-mail. I uploaded it on Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting all beans name no matter if they are initialized or not

```
String [] beans = context.getBeanDefinitionNames();
```

You could autowire Scheduler.

Comment: Can you propose some solution, please?

Comment: May I send you a code example to your e-mail so you can review and test it?